# Tabla con relación consigo misma Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, api-fluent

Me veo atascado en definir una tabla para los Catálogos de Cuentas, estos pueden ser de *control* o *auxiliar* es decir si es de *control* es una cuenta padre lo que significa que tendrá sub-cuentas que serian cuentas hijas y las cuentas de tipo *auxiliar* no tendrán cuentas hijas.

Por ejemplo:

```
1 – Activos.//control
1.0 – Activos Corrientes.//control
1.0.1 – Efectivos en Caja y Bancos. //control
1.0.1.1 – Caja General.//auxiliar
```

Ese es un ejemplo de la jerarquía de los catálogos de cuentas, el punto es que me gustaría tener acceso a la única cuenta padre de una cuenta y a la lista de cuentas hijas de una cuenta. Pero no se como estructurar el modelo.

He intentado de esta forma:

### Modelo:

```
public class CatalogoCuenta
{
    [Key]
    public int NumeroCuenta { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string NombreCuenta { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public FuenteCuenta Fuente { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public GrupoCuenta Grupo { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public ISR Retencion { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public TipoCuenta TipoCuenta { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public TipoIngreso TipoIngreso { get; set; }

    public int? CuentaPadreId { get; set; }
    public List<RelacionCuentaHijo> CuentasHijas { get; set; }
    public RelacionCuentaPadre CuentaPadre { get; set; }
}
public class RelacionCuentaHijo
{
    [Key]
    public int RelacionId { get; set; }
    public int CuentaHijoId { get; set; }
    public CatalogoCuenta CuentaHijo { get; set; }
}
public class RelacionCuentaPadre
{
    [Key]
    public int RelacionId { get; set; }
    public int CuentaPadreId { get; set; }
    public CatalogoCuenta CuentaPadre { get; set; }
}
```

Pero me he dado cuenta que este modelo no hace nada mas bien necesitaria algun modelo con relacion doble, es decir, con el Id de la cuenta y el Id de la cuenta con la que se relaciona. Por ejemplo:

```
public class RelacionCuentaHijo
{
    [Key]
    public int RelacionId { get; set; }
    public int CuentaHijoId { get; set; }
    public CatalogoCuenta CuentaHijo { get; set; }
    public int CuentaId { get; set; }
    public CatalogoCuenta Cuenta { get; set; }
}
```

Pero no se como hacer para que esto funcione y que en `CuentaHijoId` se guarde el Id de la cuenta hija y en `CuentaId` el Id de la cuenta que la tiene como padre.

También tengo una duda si debo crear esas dos tablas para hacer esa relación o con una basta.
Utilizo *api fluent* para configurar las relaciones presentada en el modelo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He logrado obtener un resultado que me satisface la necesidad.

### Modelo

```
public class CatalogoCuenta
{
    [Key]
    public int NumeroCuenta { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string NombreCuenta { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public FuenteCuenta Fuente { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public GrupoCuenta Grupo { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public ISR Retencion { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public TipoCuenta TipoCuenta { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public TipoIngreso TipoIngreso { get; set; }

    public int RelacionCuentaId { get; set; }
    public List<RelacionCuenta> CuentasHijas { get; set; }
    public RelacionCuenta RelacionCuenta { get; set; }
}
public class RelacionCuenta
{
    [Key]
    public int RelacionId { get; set; }
    public int CuentaHijoId { get; set; }
    public CatalogoCuenta CuentaHijo { get; set; }
    public int CuentaPadreId { get; set; }
    public CatalogoCuenta CuentaPadre { get; set; }
}
```

De esta manera puedo tener una tabla externa que almacena todas las cuentas hijas y la cuenta padre.

Para lograr esto utilizo el siguiente codigo con fluent api:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  modelBuilder.Entity<RelacionCuenta>()
          .HasRequired(x => x.CuentaHijo)
          .WithOptional(x => x.RelacionCuenta)
          .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

  modelBuilder.Entity<RelacionCuenta>()
          .HasRequired(x => x.CuentaPadre)
          .WithMany(x => x.CuentasHijas)
          .HasForeignKey(x => x.CuentaPadreId)
          .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
}
```

Entonces es posible obtener las cuentas con su cuenta padre tan solo haciendo:

```
var cuentasConSuPadre = await db.CatalogoCuenta.Include(x => x.RelacionCuenta).ToListAsync();
```

Y de esta manera obtengo las cuentas con una lista de las cuentas hijas:

```
var cuentasConSusHijas = await db.CatalogoCuenta.Include(x => x.CuentasHijas).ToListAsync();
```